# Is Magento 1 good to start learning?

Tags: magento-1.9

As a junior developer,  I wanted to add up to my skill and try to learn the Commerce platform Magento. Should I start learning from magento 1, before I get to proceed for Magento 2 ? Is Magento 1 still industry used ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can start directly with Magento 2. Because Magento 1 has a different code architecture than Magento 2. The more experience you have in PHP systems, the lower the curve when migrating to Magento. However, I would recommend going straight to the newest version of Magento.
Apart from the architecture, Magento 2 is what is currently being used and maintained. There is a plethora of extensions that can help you learn, simply by searching on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 is probably older than you are. Your time and energy will be much better spent learning to develop with Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with Magento 2 because of these Advantages :

- Magento 2 comes with the new feature of the E-Commerce Functionalities e.g Page Builder.
- Improved Performance: Magento 2 is faster than Magento 1. It has a faster page load speed and can handle more orders per hour.
- Better Scalability: Magento 2 has improved scalability and can handle - larger amounts of data and traffic compared to Magento 1.
- Enhanced Checkout Process: Magento 2 has a streamlined and faster checkout process, which can lead to higher conversion rates.
- Responsive Design: Magento 2 comes with a responsive design that works well on different devices and screen sizes, making it easier for customers to shop on mobile devices.
- Improved Admin Interface: Magento 2 has an improved admin interface that is more user-friendly and easier to use than the admin interface of Magento 1.
- Advanced Search Capabilities: Magento 2 comes with advanced search capabilities that allow customers to find products more easily.
- Better Security: Magento 2 has improved security features, including two-factor authentication and improved password hashing algorithms, which make it more secure than Magento 1.
- Easier Upgrades: Magento 2 has a more streamlined upgrade process, making it easier to upgrade to the latest version of the software.

Answer (score 0):

Go straight to Magento 2. Magento 1 s obsolete. The the CE version can be installed on a local machine for practicing development. You can use Warden and Docker to install. Below is a link to Warden.

https://docs.warden.dev/environments/magento2.html